# Enum dependency property not working with intellisense

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have the following UserControl

```cs
public partial class TestCtrl : UserControl
{
    public enum Alignments
    {
        HORIZONTAL,
        VERTICAL
    }

    public TestCtrl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public static DependencyProperty AlignmentProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    "Alignment",
    typeof(Alignments),
    typeof(TestCtrl),
    new PropertyMetadata(Alignments.HORIZONTAL));

    public Alignments Alignment
    {
        get
        {
            return (Alignments)GetValue(AlignmentProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(AlignmentProperty, value);
        }
    }
}
```

The property works but auto-complete does not detect possible values for the property when using it in xaml.

Comment: Odd.  Autocomplete works for me with your code (in Visual C# 2010 Express).  Does it help if you build the solution, or restart Visual Studio?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer, turns out according to [this howto](http://timdams.wordpress.com/2012/05/30/creating-an-intellisense-compatible-enum-based-dependency-property/) you need to declare the enum outside of the class with the dependency property